# Firestore - How do I add a new key value pair to a document containing a list of maps?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document which looks like:

[image]

So the document only has a single array which contains multiple maps. To some of those maps (only if the map contains the key "color" with a value of "red" AND it contains the key "name" with a value of "food3") I want to add a new key value pair (e.g. key "test1", value "test2").

So the document should look like:

[image]

How can I do this in Java? Not sure if this matters, but not all maps follow that same structure. Some of those maps can contain arrays too.

Comment: You will have to read the document, modify the list array in memory, then update its entire contents back to the document.  There is no shortcut to this.

Comment: @DougStevenson So I modified it in memory. Now I have a list which looks like: List<Map<String, String>> list which contains the new data. How do I rewrite the document so that it deletes the old data and instead uses the new list? Would it be

`ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = db.collection("data").document("one").set(list);` because set will overwrite the old list automatically? And is List<Map<String, String>> correct since it's possible that the maps can contain arrays too? I don't understand how a map in firestore can contain both key value pairs and other data structures like lists too.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

insted of using set use update

```
ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = db.collection("data").document("one").upsate(list);
```